# how to find the grammar of this Language?

Tags: palindrome, context-free-grammar, computation-theory, chomsky-normal-form, chomsky-hierarchy

How to find the grammar of this language: La = {ww^r: w e {0,1}^*, w ends with 1} ?
r: is reverse

Here is my solution:

```
S -> 0S0|1S1| 0|1|E(epsilon)
```

What can I change here or is the solution the right one?

Comment: What is `r` in your language definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase

> by using chomsky

is not correct. "chomsky" is not a tool or approach that can be "used". Moreover, the proposed CFG is not correct for the language, because it can yield strings of odd length, and also strings in which `w` ends with 0. The following grammar works for the language. However, it is not in Chomsky Normal Form (CNF). You can readily convert it to a grammar that is in CNF if you want.

```
S -> 1S1 | 0S0 | 11
```

This is an equivalent grammar that is in CNF:

```
S0 -> XT | YU | XX
S -> XT | YU | XX
T -> SX
U -> SY
X -> 1
Y -> 0
```

Comment: How to proove the condition "w ends with 1"?

Comment: The strings in your language La need to be of even length. The last symbol of the first half, which is `w` in the definition, and the first symbol of the second half, i.e., `w^r` have to be 1 by the definition. Hence, we use the rule `S -> 11`. This rule guaranties that `w` ends with 1.